# Pausing/playing and stopping a Node stream

Tags: node.js, audio-streaming

Am working on creating a basic audio player on a raspberry pi. I have a basic mp3 player on the client with the basic controls...play/pause and stop. When the user clicks on play, socket sends a mp3 url to the server which is using node which captures the url and plays it on the speakers. Am having a problem with making the stream pause/resume play on the server. Below is my code

```
var app = require("express")();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
var lame = require('lame');   
var request = require('request');
var Speaker = require('speaker');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
var playing;
var decoder = new lame.Decoder();

playing = socket.on('play', function(data){
 var stream;
 stream = request(data.songurl);

 decoder.on('format', function(){
   mpg123Util.setVolume(decoder.mh, 1.0)
})
 return stream;

 stream.pipe(decoder).pipe(speaker);
 setTimeout(function(){
   console.log('pausing')
   stream.unpipe(decoder).unpipe(speaker);
 }, 10000);

   stream.on('end', function(){
     console.log('ended')
     stream.unpipe(decoder).unpipe(speaker);
    })
  })

 socket.on('pause', function(data){
   // console.log(playing)
  playing.unpipe(decoder).unpipe(speaker);
 })
```

Am getting an error 'Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined' when I click on the pause button because 'stream' has not been defined at that time. Is there a way of detecting whether there is an existing stream and how to pause/resume that stream?

Comment: Why do you want to pipe a stream into something when it should be paused? What is `ps`? What is the value of `ps.pause`?

Comment: Perhaps you want to do [`stream.pause()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) instead...?

Comment: ps.pause is something I was trying out which didn't work. The problem am having is how to detect an existing stream and assign that stream to a variable...not sure if this makes sense. This is because their is already a stream playing when the user clicks on pause i.e. User clicks on play to start the stream and when user clicks on pause I need to detect the existing stream and pause it. How can I do that?

Comment: Move `var stream` out of the `if` statement. Set it to the actual stream within the `if` statement. If action is `'pause'`, check if the stream is really set and pause it if it is.

Comment: I've edited the function and also added in a 10 second timeout . Am getting a 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' on the settimeout function for `stream.unpipe(decoder).unpipe(speaker);` Seems its not possible to unpipe at that stage. Any ideas?

Comment: You are still defining your stream within the play event - it has to be defined outside so other events have access to it.

Comment: Am defining the stream within the play event however am returning the stream to the playing variable which is outside the event. Even so I still get the same error

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alaneor/oqfjtr3v/1). Also, make sure to click the JSHint button, you will see some problems in your code like missing closing braces etc.